# read tcp [addr]->[addr] use of closed network connection

Tags: go, ssl, networking

I'm using Google's *simplehttp2server* go-lang program to run some tests and have encountered a recurring error. Upon executing the TLS handshake I receive the following error:

> 2019/12/12 12:42:55 http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:36202: read tcp 127.0.0.1:5000->127.0.0.1:36202: use of closed network connection

I have updated my go version to 1.13.5 from 1.12.9 and tried two browsers (brave + chrome) plus curl and receive the same error code each time. It happens over HTTP/2 and HTTP/1.1. I have seem other answers from across the web but am still running into this error ([ex1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/_DA71u569uw), [ex2](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21760), [ex3](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/issues/439), [ex4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385487/golang-http-having-use-of-closed-network-connection-error)).

Very much appreciate any feedback, advice, or admonishment. Anything to help the migraine this problem is giving me!

edit: screenshot from my curl and running of simplehttp2server
[example image from curl and simplehttp2server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtztO.png)

Comment: could you post the code you have?

Comment: alas, there is not a real code example. i've added in a screenshot from the curl i ran that encounters the error

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/simplehttp2server/blob/master/simplehttp2server.go

Comment: i've narrowed it down further to the `conn.go` file in the crypto/tls package. the `readFromUntil` method on line 609 of this file is throwing the error I'm seeing: https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/conn.go

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when you have two websockets connected to a singular address using the same port from the same machine. One of the websockets will be able to connect fine but the other wont be able to make the connection.

I was making the same mistake and when I removed the duplicate connection the error resolved.